# Display grouped data separately in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on website where i need to perform search and display the results.For example if i search for a product named `product1` and if it comes under 2 categories say category1 and category2,then i need to display it as

```
Category 1:
-----------
product1

Category 2:
----------
product1
```

Here product1 represents the image and other details about the product which are in database.I am fetching data from the database which matches my search criteria and separating it according to the category.Now i need to display it as shown above.I am trying to do somethink like [this](http://www.flipkart.com/search/a/all?fk-search=all&query=sony&vertical=all&dd=0&autosuggest%5Bas%5D=off&autosuggest%5Bas-submittype%5D=default-search&autosuggest%5Bas-grouprank%5D=0&autosuggest%5Bas-overallrank%5D=0&autosuggest%5Borig-query%5D=&autosuggest%5Bas-shown%5D=on&Search=%C2%A0&otracker=start&_r=RsuiHvNUWzIGQmMYN5OGLg--&_l=kHKbQQIaxhdVidRxlMIbvQ--&ref=3e02b3dc-d02a-4baa-af9c-0c9904d1759b&selmitem=All%20Categories&ab_buk=disabled) How can i do it.I saw somewhere that itemdatabound event can be used for this purpose,if so how can use it.Please help me solve this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DataTable dlcat = new DataTable();

        SqlCommand cmdcat = new SqlCommand("select CategoryName from tblCategoryMaster where CategoryMasterSequenceNumber='" + catno + "'", lcon);
        lcon.Open(); 
        cmdcat.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdcat);
        da.Fill(dlcat);
        dlouter.DataSource = dlcat;
        dlouter.DataBind();



<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server"  Text='<% eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" Width="197px">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="catImage" ImageUrl='<% eval("ImageURL") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>


protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label catId = e.Item.FindControl("lblCategory") as Label ;
        DataList List2= e.Item.FindControl("DataList2") as DataList ;

        DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();
        //tbl2

= GetCategoryItemBasedonCategoryID(catId.Text)          database call function for fetch data to bind the second datalist
        List2.DataSource = tbl2;
        List2.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: yes all the category names should be there. Alongs with that you will get the products related to the category in the second list(inner)

Comment: you are not getting the product list?

Comment: see i am getting output something like this cat1 cat1 cat1 cat2 cat2,also that itemdatabound event is not firing.

Comment: check with ur database columns. it may have all these items cat1, cat1,cat1,cat2,cat2.... do u knw how to craete itemdatabound vent?

Comment: I think u didnt understand my problem properly.what i am doing now is when i type a string in searchbox and click search button,I am searching for the string in my database(product table).If there is any match in any category i am getting the category id of the matched product and using that id i am fetching the categoryname from category table to bind the outer datalist.

Answer (score 0):

you can use datalist for this purpose. Nested datalist is the solution. You have to place a datalist inside another datalist. Then on the dataitembound event of the outer datalist you have to bind the inner datalist. I will show you some sample codes for esily understanding.

code

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server"  Text='<% eval("categoryid") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="catImage" ImageUrl='<% eval("ImageURL") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>




 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();



DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        DataRow datarow;

        tbl.Columns.Add ("categoryid");

        datarow=tbl.NewRow ();
//this value from database
        datarow ["categoryid"]="Cat1";

        tbl.Rows.Add (datarow );
         //tbl= Take datafromdatabasetoBindtheFirstDataList();

        DataList1.DataSource = tbl;
        DataList1.DataBind();



}
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label catId = e.Item.FindControl("lblCategory") as Label ;
    DataList List2= e.Item.FindControl("DataList2") as DataList ;

    DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();
    //tbl2= GetCategoryItemBasedonCategoryID(catId.Text)          database call function for fetch data to bind the second datalist
    List2.DataSource = tbl2;
    List2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: wait 4 the next code i have updated the samples on the answer

Comment: when i try bind the outer datalist which has a label its not binding.

Comment: on the page load event u have to bind the outer datalist. when you specify the datatable u have to define the column also.

Comment: Actually i am doing it inside a method where i am fetching category name depending on the item searched..

Comment: how do u specify ur datatable? is it by datacolumn?

Comment: SqlCommand cmdcat = new SqlCommand("select CategoryName from tblCategoryMaster where CategoryMasterSequenceNumber='" + catno + "'", lcon);
                    //lcon.Open();
                    cmdcat.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdcat);
                    da.Fill(dlcat);
                    dlouter.DataSource = dlcat;
                    dlouter.DataBind();

Comment: k here you have to take the categoryid from database. then only u can fetch the relevant data based on your category

Comment: is there a categoryid in your product table?

Comment: u can specify as  <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server"  Text='<% eval("categoryName") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: i specified it and when i bind the datatable to datalist all the category name in that datatable are binding to the label in the datalist.yes i have a category id in my database and using that only i fetch the Category name.

Comment: then add a new label for categoryid. on my updated answer i have specified the protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) method use it and rebind your product table to the inner datalist. I have taken the inner datalist inside this method

Comment: you are not getting the product list?